# Bitwise operator ( & ) not working in Jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I have had this issue for almost now a month. Whenever I write code in jupyter notebooks and try to write the bitwise operator symbol (&), it brings a funny symbol when i press shift + 7 for & operator

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you have the same problem when you paste the `&` from the clipboard?

Comment: Just tried it here and could not reproduce. It is probably a key binding you have on `Shift + 7`, have you tried on another apps (such as notepad, web browser and others)?

Comment: So Am I understanding correctly that the symbol looks wrong in code mode but correct in comments?  Does the symbol act correctly but just look wrong?

Comment: When I use Notepad, or another app, even jupyter lab, I get the correct symbol. The funny symbol only appears in jupyter notebook.

Comment: Even if I just paste it, I get the same problem.

Comment: Yes @KyleParsons the symbol looks wrong in code but correct in comments and other apps like Notepad, vscode, and even jupyterLab. Fortunately, even with the funny symbol, the code runs correctly. but it's just annoying seeing the funny symbol in code